# How to change host in Keycloak update password email

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

We use Keycloak REST api to send update password email to users. In my setup Keycloak and application making REST calls to Keycloak (using keycloak admin client library) is deployed inside Kubernetes cluster. From my application I am using Kubernetes service name to talk to keycloak.

e.g. http://keycloak-http:8100/auth

With this setup, update password link in email becomes like this
http://keycloak-http:8100/auth/realms/test/login-actions/action-token?key=somekey

So I need to change only host in this URL.

I looked at executeActions.ftl file in keycloak theme and it doesn't have any specific parameter for just host which I can customize.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm running keycloak like this as well, and after a lot of trial and error, I settled on setting the server name explicitly  using -Dkeycloak.hostname.provider=fixed -Dkeycloak.hostname.fixed.hostname=<theHostName>

Comment: Hi Burak, Thanks for quick reply. I tried this and I see this warning on keycloak startup
"fixed hostname provider is deprecated, please switch to the default hostname provider".
Can you please point me to the place where you found this information.

Comment: I no longer remember where I found this. Googling "keycloak fixed hostname" brings a few links.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem using default host name provider during keycloak server start up (-Dkeycloak.hostname.provider=default) and setting up frontend URL as my desired hostname in realm settings. Thanks Burak for pointing me to right direction.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Keycloak 9+, I used the "Frontend URL" in the Realm Setting to specify the hostname.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and it turns out that by default, the host name is filled with the request hostname. (Using Keycloak 6.0.1)

All i had to do was to trigger the email generation with the hostname i wanted in the email.
--> Trigger the update action from the url you need (and that is accessible)
http://externalurl.keycloak.com/auth/...

You can also change the hostname provider, to use a FixedHostnameProvider, or a custom one (it is RequestHostnameProvider by default)
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_hostname